# Can we offer 'Offers' in In-App-Purchase?

Tags: ios, paypal, xcode6, in-app-purchase

I want to know can I use `In-app-purchase` to the following things.

1. I want to use IAP to avail an deal in stores. (to get 50% in that store).
2. Suppose my IAP is for 10USD but for today I'm offering 10% off that purchase. So for today it will be for 9USD.

As mention in the apple's [guidelines 11.3](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies), I guess I cant use IAP for #1

Can I use `Paypal` instead?
What would be the best to use for such purchase type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my understanding and experience, There's no way for percentage offer for In App Purchase.
You will just need to create two IAP products.

Also, in app purchase is used for extend app's functionalities.
And Paypal and other payment sources are used to sell the products inside the app which is not related to app functions.

For example, let's say I am developing a shopping app.

You can use in app purchase for retailer functionalities while normal users cannot post their product when using this app.

But you will need to use paypal for normal users to buy products that retailers posted.